# Computing the number of rainy months for a given data set in Python

Tags: python

So my homework question is this:

> `rainfall_mi` is a string that contains the average number of inches of rainfall in Michigan for every month (in inches) with every month separated by a comma. Write code to compute the number of months that have more than 3 inches of rainfall. Store the result in the variable `num_rainy_months`. In other words, count the number of items with values > 3.0.

The output of `rainfall_mi` is 5 but I just can't seem to get it right, plus I feel like I'm making a small error somewhere that I'm missing.

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
rainfall_mi_list = list(rainfall_mi)
rainfall_mi_split = rainfall_mi.split(",")
num_rainy_months = 0
for x in rainfall_mi:
    if num_rainy_months > 3.0:
        num_rainy_months = x
    else:
        num_rainy_months = x
```

Comment: `x` in your loop is a string. to compare it to a `float` you need to convert it to a `float` as well: `x = float(x)`. and probably: `num_rainy_months += 1` only in one branch if the `if`... (there is not much sense in doing the same in the `if` and the `else` branch...)

Comment: Are you using python 2? That loop should crash in the 2nd iteration...

Comment: Wherever I put num_rainy_months += 1 and x = float(x) I get errors, where do I do these

Comment: Im using python 3

Comment: What are you trying to do with `rainfall_mi_list = list(rainfall_mi)`? It's not used anywhere else in the program, delete it.

Comment: @Guimoute Deleted.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several small mistakes:

- `x` in your loop is a string. to compare it to a `float` you need to convert it to a `float` as well: `x = float(x)`
- and probably: `num_rainy_months += 1` only in one branch of the `if`... (there is not much sense in doing the same in the `if` and the `else` branch...)
- you should be iterating over `rainfall_mi_split` and comparint `3.0` to `x` and not `num_rainy_months`

all in all:

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
rainfall_mi_split = rainfall_mi.split(",")
num_rainy_months = 0
for x in rainfall_mi_split:
    x = float(x)
    if x > 3.0:
        num_rainy_months += 1

print(num_rainy_months)
```

---

side-note: this could also be done in one line:

```
num_rainy_months = sum(1 for x in rainfall_mi.split(",") if float(x) > 3.0)
```

Comment: @hiro protagonist: you can sum the boolean values directly too. `num_rainy_months = sum((float(x) > 3 for x in rainfall_mi.split(",")))`

Comment: @Guimoute very elegant! but maybe a bit much for here... (summing boolean variables is not for beginners...)

Comment: Haha agreed, but summing a list comprehension or a generator might be a bit much too ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple small things that you've gotten wrong. First of all, you are not comparing the actual rainfall to 3.0.

num_rainy_months, as you've just declared, is equal to 0, x is the value you want to check:

```
num_rainy_months = 0 # this is fine
for x in rainfall_mi:
    if x > 3.0: 
        # code
```

as @hiro protagonist pointed out, x is a *string*, not a float, so you want to get rid of white space and cast as float:

```
num_rainy_months = 0 # this is fine
for x in rainfall_mi:
    if float(x.strip()) > 3.0: 
       # code
```

You also don't want to set num_rainy_months equal to x, as x is your rainfall value, you just want to add 1 if x is greater than 3.0, and you don't need an else, because if it isn't greater than 3.0 you just want to ignore it:

```
num_rainy_months = 0 # this is fine
for x in rainfall_mi: # each x is a rainfall value
    if float(x.strip()) > 3.0: # if the rainfall value, as float, is greater than 3
        num_rainy_months += 1 # add 1 to rainy months
```

Answer (score 0):

In a procedural way, you want to basically count all of the items which have a real (numeric) value above 3, which is easily accomplished:

- Get a list of numbers (not strings) - done with `rainfall_mi.split(",")`
- Check to see if the number is greater than 3.0 (done below):

  ```
  int x = 0
  for rainfall in rainfall_mi.split(","):
      if float(rainfall) > 3.0:
          x += 1
  ```
- Print out the result (done with `print(x)`).

Essentially, you had the structure, but you were missing:

- Checking the *actual* value in the list against a known float
- Converting the values from the list into floats so they could be numerically compared

A more Pythonic approach would result in a reduction.  You could eschew any extra data structures or variables, and express this in a list comprehension, which does the same thing.

```
print(len([x for x in rainfall_mi.split(",") if float(x) > 3.0]))
```

This does:

- Splits out the elements of your string into individual numbers which were separated by a comma
- Adds these values to a separate list (`[x for x in rainfall_mi.split(",")]`)
- Filters out the values which are below the desired threshold `if float(x) > 3.0`
- Checks the length of the resultant new structure.

Answer (score 0):

rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"

num_rainy_months = 0

x = rainfall_mi.split(",")

for i in x:

```
if float(i) > 3.0:

    num_rainy_months += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer is identical to the already accepted answer; answers that don't add anything new from existing answers are frowned upon. Also, it's recommended to have a description accompanying code instead of having an answer entirely of code.

Answer (score 0):

And this here is how I did it, hope that helps:

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"

rainfall_mi_list = rainfall_mi.split(", ")

num_rainy_months = 0
for n in range(0, len(rainfall_mi_list)):
    if float(rainfall_mi_list[n]) > 3: 
        num_rainy_months += 1

print(num_rainy_months)
```

Answer (score -1):

There were several mistakes here. You need a list of numbers, first of all. Second, what you want is "When rainfall is greater than 3, consider it a rainy month, and count it." What you were doing is asking if the number of rainy months was greater that three, which it wasn't because you set it to zero, and then you just recursively set the number of rainy months to each x until x ran out. Please read the documentation of for loops in python.

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
rainfall_mi_split = rainfall_mi.split(",")
rainfall_mi_split=[float(x) for x in rainfall_mi_split]
num_rainy_months = 0
for x in rainfall_mi_split:

    if x > 3.0:
        num_rainy_months +=1
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted this at the same time the other answer came out.